# Sap B1 Quantity Field on Recommendation Form

Tags: sapb1

I make some inserts on ORCM table by programmatically. Everything looks normal on database. Here is the insert query for ORCM table:

```
insert into ORCM (DocEntry,ObjAbs,ObjType,ItemCode,DueDate,OrderType,Quantity,UOM,CardCode,Warehouse,Price,Origin,Status,UserSign,DocDate,ReleasDate) values ("+mx+"," + objAbs +",199,'"+sale.itemCode+"',GETDATE(),'P',"+sale.quantity+",'','V10000','01',0,'M','O',1,GETDATE(),GETDATE())
```

But the quantity field on recommendation form is coming empty.
I couldn't find why this is happenning.

Comment: You should not update the database in this manner. Direct updates to SQL tables will invalidate your SAP support. You must use DI-API to add a new document to the database. DI-API will validate your data and will probably also solve the problem with the quantity.

Comment: I couldn't find recommendation(objType=199--ORCM) on BoObjectTypes. How can I insert into ORCM table using di api?

Comment: Sorry @yenicemerve I don't know this. The DI-API does not give 100% coverage of all internal functions of B1, it may not be possible.